# Pass dynamic button id to click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I need some help with the following:

```
                //exampleList has 3 rows

                int count = 1;
                foreach (var item in exampleList)
                {
                Button btnExample = new Button();
                btnExample.ID = "btnExample" + count.ToString();
                btnExample.Text = "example";
                btnExample.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnExample_Click);
                count++;
                }
```

This piece of code will result in 3 buttons. All 3 buttons have the same event (btnExmple_Click). Those 3 fields have the following id's after running this code:

- btnExample1
- btnExample2
- btnExample3

Now, when I click either one of those buttons, I need to redirect to another page and pass the id of the button. So, if I click the second button I want to pass btnExample2 with it. My question, can I do this in ASP.NET itself without the use of JS/Jquery? And if this is possible, how do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your button handler :

```
protected void btnExample_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   Button btn = (Button) sender;

   string id = btn.ID;

   //redirect page ...
}
```

Convert the `sender` object to be of type `Button` and then get the ID.